# Java - Get specific word from string

Tags: java, string, split

I have a string that is like this:

```
String programList = "List of programs: explorer.exe, conhost.exe, java.exe, something.exe..";
```

I want to create every word that has the ".exe" to its own string, like this:

```
String program1 = "explorer.exe";
String program2 = "conhost.exe";
String program3 = "java.ex";
String program4 = "something.exe";
```

Comment: Great!  What have you tried?

Comment: Sorry, I have know idea how to do this.

Comment: Ok.. Let me give you a hint. Search for string.split method on google.. Try something and post your code here

Comment: Check out Regular Expressions + http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html

Comment: use programList.split(...) ,have a tutorial

Comment: Youc can split the  string using , and and first sting by : you get exact solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method from the `String` class, passing an appropriate regular expression as parameter:

```
String[] programs = programList.split("(,|:) ");
```

Now all positions from `programs[1]` up to `programs[programs.length-1]` will each contain a program. It's trivial to extract them:

```
String program1 = programs[1];
String program2 = programs[2];
String program3 = programs[3];
String program4 = programs[4];
```